# Condense body class conditonal statements with SASS

Tags: css, sass

Is there anyway to condense this code.  We actually have 12 sport sites and have multi areas where we have to test the base class of body.  It just takes up a lot of space.  I was using less but there wasnt much power to do that but converted to sass which could have an option to condense this but I am not well versed yet.

```
    $otherBaseLinkColor: #08c;
    $otherColor: #000000;

    $basketballBaseLinkColor: #d18000;
    $basketballColor: #ff9900;

    $footballBaseLinkColor: #99753d;
    $footballColor: #99743d;

    $volleyballBaseLinkColor: #FF0000;
    $volleyballColor: #FF0000;

    $hockeyBaseLinkColor: #44a0fc;
    $hockeyColor: #1d9cf2;

    $baseballBaseLinkColor: #1BA514;
    $baseballColor: #1BA514;

    a, a:visited, a:active {
        .other & {
            color: $otherBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .basketball & {
            color: $basketballBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .football & {
            color: $footballBaseLinkColor
        }

        .volleyball & {
            color: $volleyballBaseLinkColor;
        }
    }

.pool {
        .other & {
            color: $otherBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .basketball & {
            color: $basketballBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .football & {
            color: $footballBaseLinkColor
        }

        .volleyball & {
            color: $volleyballBaseLinkColor;
        }
    }


.cell-container{
        .other & {
            color: $otherBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .basketball & {
            color: $basketballBaseLinkColor;
        }

        .football & {
            color: $footballBaseLinkColor
        }

        .volleyball & {
            color: $volleyballBaseLinkColor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Sass could be minified when compiling with an appropriate flag, but I don’t understand if you just need to do so. BTW, your syntax should be a little different to work properly.

Comment: Are you looking for a small SASS code or a small compiled code?

Comment: Small SASS Code.  I added two more classes to show the duplication of the code.  I want something easier to include into the scss that wont take up so much space everytime I need to set the color based on the sport of the site.  Imagine 12 sports in all in multiple places, takes up alot of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could organize your colors in a 2-level SASS [`map`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) and use [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) to cycle over all the defined sports. Then you could retrieve the `baselinkcolor` property using `map-get`:

```
$colors: (
    "other"      : ("baselinkcolor": #0088cc, "color": #000000),
    "basketball" : ("baselinkcolor": #d18000, "color": #ff9900),
    "football"   : ("baselinkcolor": #99753d, "color": #99743d)
);


a, a:visited, a:active, .pool, .cell-container {
   @each $sport, $values in $colors {
      .#{$sport} & {
          color: map-get($values, "baselinkcolor");
      }
   }
}
```

The result is

```
.other a, .other a:visited, .other a:active, 
.other .pool, 
.other .cell-container {
  color: #0088cc;
}

.basketball a, .basketball a:visited, .basketball a:active, 
.basketball .pool, 
.basketball .cell-container {
  color: #d18000;
}

.football a, .football a:visited, .football a:active, 
.football .pool, 
.football .cell-container {
  color: #99753d;
}

...
```

And, as you can see, not only the SCSS code is reduced but also the output is less redundant.

You can test it by copying the SCSS code on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm but I had to remove the " on the values in the list.